# Javascript setTimeout and Chrome Workers, I don't get it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following files: (inc.js is included in my html page)

**inc.js**

```
var field = new Worker('ajax.js');
field.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    document.getElementById('fieldToUpdate').innerHTML = data[0];
}, false);
field.postMessage(0);
```

**ajax.js**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
function getData() {
    xhr.open('get', 'field.php');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processData;
    xhr.send(null);
}
function processData() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        self.postMessage(xhr.responseText);
        setTimeout(getData, 5000);
    }
}
onmessage = function() {
    setTimeout(getData, 5000);
}
```

My Problem is now, that this Script doesn't make one http request each 5 seconds but it starts as soon as one is finished.

Comment: AJAX is already asynchronous. Why do you use Web Workers to make AJAX requests ?

Comment: The scripts are a lot bigger than that one here, and sometimes doing expensive calculations on the resultset. Additionally there are more than one of these scripts on the same page.